# Soving equation $y' = f(x, y) + g(x, y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a differential equation $y' = f(x, y) + g(x, y)$, where $f$ and $g$ are continuous, can we solve it by splitting it into two:

$y_1' = f(x, y)$ and $y_2' = g(x, y)$

From that we have that $y_1 = \int f(x, y) dx + C_1$ and $y_2 = \int g(x, y) dx + C_2$ and $y_1' + y_2' = y'$

Can we use that, and the fact that the derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives, to make the final solution $y = y_1 + y_2$?

I suppose not, but I'm not sure why not, so I would appreciate some pointers on that.

Comment: This is not a solution. The integral $F(x,y)=\int f(x,y)\,dx$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$, so $F(x,y)$ is not a solution of $y'=f(x,y)$. And even if $y_1$ were a solution of $y'=f(x,y)$ and $y_2$ were a solution of $y'=g(x,y)$, you would get $y'=y_1'+y_2'=f(x,y_1)+g(x,y_2)$ instead.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Isn't that called implicit formula for solutions (e.g. $y_1 = \int f(x, y_1) dx + C$)?

Comment: S11n $F(x,y)=C$ is an implicit form solution of the *exact* DE
$$F_x(x,y)+F_y(x,y)y'=0.$$ Observe that the partial derivative $F_y=\partial F/\partial y$ is missing from the DE you started with. Furthermore, there is no such way to add two implicit solutions like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is you have the differential and integral formulas for $y_1$ and $y_2$ wrong. $y_1$ and $y_2$ are different variables than $y$. You cannot solve $$y_1' = f(x,y)$$
because it still involves $y$ and you do not know what $y$ is. $y_1' = f(x,y)$ establishes a relationship between $y_1$ and $y$, but you can select any sufficiently regular $y$ arbitrarily, and find its corresponding $y_1$, (up to a constant, which I won't bother to keep pointing out since we all know about it). You don't get some specific $y_1$ as a solution to this. Similar remarks apply to $y_2$.

Perhaps you meant that $y_1' = f(x, y_1)$ and $y_2'=g(x,y_2)$. And presumably you actually have solutions for these two problems. But you still have an issue. If you set $y = y_1 + y_2$, then what you get is $$y' = f(x, y_1) + g(x, y_2)$$ not $$y' = f(x, y) + g(x, y)$$ the problem you were trying to solve. Unless $f,g$ are such that $f(x,y_1) = f(x, y_1 + y_2)$ and $g(x, y_2) = g(x, y_1 + y_2)$, this isn't going to be a solution to the original problem.